# TensorFlowLite.Tensor to UUImage

Tags: ios, swift, tensorflow

I am new with swift, TFlite and IOS. I succeed to convert, run my model. However at the end, I need to reconstruct an image. My TFlite model return a [TFLite.tensor](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/api_docs/swift/Structs/Tensor) `Float32` 4d - shape (1, height, width, 3).

```
let outputTensor: Tensor
outputTensor = try myInterpreter.output(at: 0)
```

I am looking to make a RGB picture without alpha. In python, it will like this:

```
Image.fromarray((np.array(outputTensor.data) * 255).astype(np.uint8))
```

From my understanding the best way will be to make a CVPixelBuffer, apply a CoreOS transformation (for the x255) and finally make the `UUImage`. I am deeply lost in the IOS doc, it exists many possibilities, does the community has a suggestion ?

++t

Comment: hii bro you solve this?

Comment: Indeed I did, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

From Google example, an extension of UIImage can be coded:

```
extension UIImage {
    convenience init?(data: Data, size: CGSize) {
        let width = Int(size.width)
        let height = Int(size.height)

        let floats = data.toArray(type: Float32.self)

        let bufferCapacity = width * height * 4
        let unsafePointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: bufferCapacity)
        let unsafeBuffer = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<UInt8>(
            start: unsafePointer,
            count: bufferCapacity)
        defer {
            unsafePointer.deallocate()
        }

        for x in 0..<width {
            for y in 0..<height {
                let floatIndex = (y * width + x) * 3
                let index = (y * width + x) * 4
                let red = UInt8(floats[floatIndex] * 255)
                let green = UInt8(floats[floatIndex + 1] * 255)
                let blue = UInt8(floats[floatIndex + 2] * 255)

                unsafeBuffer[index] = red
                unsafeBuffer[index + 1] = green
                unsafeBuffer[index + 2] = blue
                unsafeBuffer[index + 3] = 0
            }
        }

        let outData = Data(buffer: unsafeBuffer)

        // Construct image from output tensor data
        let alphaInfo = CGImageAlphaInfo.noneSkipLast
        let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: alphaInfo.rawValue)
            .union(.byteOrder32Big)
        let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
        guard
            let imageDataProvider = CGDataProvider(data: outData as CFData),
            let cgImage = CGImage(
                width: width,
                height: height,
                bitsPerComponent: 8,
                bitsPerPixel: 32,
                bytesPerRow: MemoryLayout<UInt8>.size * 4 * Int(size.width),
                space: colorSpace,
                bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo,
                provider: imageDataProvider,
                decode: nil,
                shouldInterpolate: false,
                intent: .defaultIntent
            )
        else {
            return nil
        }
        self.init(cgImage: cgImage)
    }
}
```

Then the image can be easily constructed from the inference of TFLite.

```
let outputTensor: Tensor
outputTensor = try decoder.output(at: 0)
image = UIImage(data: outputTensor.data, size: size) ?? UIImage()
```